# If a group $G$ has only finitely many subgroups, then show that $G$ is a finite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a group $G$ has only finitely many subgroups, then show that $G$ is a finite group.  I have no idea on how to start this question. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: What happens if $G$ be assumed to be infinite?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/22996/264

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285726/on-subgroups-of-a-group

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose $G$ were infinite.  If $G$ contains an element of infinite order, then **_**.

Otherwise, every element of $G$ has finite order, and if $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are any finite set of elements of $G$, then the subgroups $\langle x_i \rangle$ cover only finitely many elements of $G$.  Therefore *_*_.

Answer (score 7):

I think the negative form of that is easier to prove: "If a group $G$ is infinite, then it has infinitely many subgroups".

What I would then do is take a member $a\in G$ such that $\left< a \right>$ is infinite, then prove there are an infinite number of subgroups just there, and say that if no such $a$ exists, there must be infinitely many subgroups of the type $\left< a \right>$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The infinite cyclic group $\mathbb Z$ has infinitely many subgroups ($n\mathbb Z$) so every element of $G$ must have finite order.  Use this to show that there is a *finite* collection $g_1, \ldots, g_n \in G$ of elements such that every element of $G$ is of the form $g_i^j$ for some choice of $i$ and $j$.