# It is true that every group that has a finite number of subgroups is finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is true that every group that has a finite number of subgroups is finite?

I think not, but I can not find counterexamples.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322713/if-a-group-g-has-only-finitely-many-subgroups-then-show-that-g-is-a-finite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, true - look at $\langle g\rangle$ for every $g \in G$ and note that an infinite cyclic group has an infinite number of subgroups.

> $\langle g \rangle$ must be finite, and since $G$ has only a finite number of subgroups, we get that $G=\bigcup_{g \in G}\langle g \rangle$ is a *finite* union. hence $G$ must be finite after all!

Comment: This is not a proof. It only shows that every element is of finite order.

Comment: This is a hint for a proof, I do not want to give away the proof. Will add spoiler though.

Comment: Ah OK. I get the idea.

Comment: This part of that an infinite cyclic group has an infinite number of subgroups is because each $g^n$ would create a new subgroup $<g^n>$?

Comment: Yes correct Croos!